# Performances counting with combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

In the backstage there are $5$ men(A,B,C,D,E) and $5$ women (A',B',C',D',E')

There will $5$ performances and each time it will be a pair $(male,female)$.

(A, E′
),(B, A′
),(B, C′
),(B, D′
),(C, B′
),(C, D′
),(D, B′
),(E, A′
),
(E, E′
)
are not allowed.

How many possible ways to have $5$ performances if all of the performers in the backstage should be used?

I thought, I could use this way:
First I look at A being in the first pair and look for possible pairings and then go for B...etc.
But I think I can't count all this way or it's too time consuming.

Can I use the inclusion-exclusion principle in this problem, or is there a different way to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer Donald Splutterwit gave is correct if each man can be matched with each woman.  If certain pairings are prohibited, his answer does not take that into account.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig i see now

Answer (score 1):

Man $A$ can be paired up with $5$ possible women, then man $B$ can be paired up with $4$ possible woman ... the man $E$ will be paired with the last woman, so there are $5!=\color{red}{120}$ ways to pair the men & women.

If you are also concerned with the order that the couples perform occur then there will be another factor of $5!$ ... that would make $\color{blue}{14400}$ performances.

Answer (score 0):

We use a tree diagram  (split in two for clarity).

The restrictions on $B$'s partner mean $B$ is matched with either $B'$ or $E'$.

If $B$ is matched with $B'$, there are no further restrictions on $D$, but $E$ is left with only two potential partners, $C'$ and $D'$.

Consult the first tree diagram below as you read the next two paragraphs.

If $E$ is matched with $C'$, $A$ can be matched with $A'$ or $D'$.  If $A$ is matched with $A'$, $C$ must be matched with $E'$, so $D$ must be matched with $D'$.  On the other hand, if $A$ is matched with $D'$, $C$ has two potential partners, $A'$ and $E'$.  We can then match $D$ with whomever is left.

If $E$ is matched with $D'$, $A$ can be matched with $A'$ or $C'$.  If $A$ is matched with $A'$, then $C$ can be matched with $C'$ or $E'$ and $D$ can be matched with whomever is left.  If $A$ is matched with $C'$, then $C$ can be matched with $A'$ or $E'$ and $D$ can be matched with whomever is left.

[image: first_tree_diagram]

If $B$ is matched with $E'$, there are no further restrictions on $A$, but $C$ is left with only two potential partners, $A'$ and $C'$.

Consult the tree diagram below as you read the next two paragraphs.

If $C$ is matched with $A'$, $D$ is left with two potential partners, $C'$ and $D'$.  If $D$ is matched with $C'$, then $E$ can be matched with $B'$ or $D'$ and $A$ can be matched with whomever is left.  If $D$ is matched with $D'$, then $E$ can be matched with $B'$ or $C'$ and $A$ can be matched with whomever is left.

If $C$ is matched with $C'$, then $D$ can be matched with $A'$ or $D'$.  If $D$ is matched with $A'$, then $E$ can be matched with $B'$ or $D'$ and $A$ can be matched with whomever is left.  On the other hand, if $D$ is matched with $D'$, $E$ must be matched with $B'$ and $A$ with $A'$.

[image: second_tree_diagram]

By counting the leaves, we see there are $14$ solutions up to the order of the five performances.  Since those five performances can be scheduled in $5!$ ways, there are $14 \cdot 5! = 2800$ potential performance schedules.

Answer (score 0):

We use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

There are $5!$ ways to match male and female performers. From these, we must exclude those arrangements that include excluded pairs.

One excluded pair:  There are $9$ choices for the excluded pair and $4!$ ways to match the remaining pairs.  Hence, there are $9 \cdot 4!$ such cases.

Two excluded pairs:  The excluded pairs must use different men and different women.

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(B,A'), (B,C'), (B,D')\}$:  $3$ choices

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(C,B'), (C,D')\}$: $2$ choices

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(D,B')\}$: $1$ choice

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(E,A')\}$: $1$ choice

$\{(B,A'), (B,C')\} \times \{(C,B'), (C,D')\}$: $4$ choices

$\{(B,D')\} \times \{(C,B')\}$: $1$ choice

$\{(B,A'), (B,C'), (B,D')\} \times \{(D,B')\}$: $3$ choice

$\{(B,A')\} \times \{(E,E')\}$: $1$ choice

$\{(B,C'), (B,D')\} \times \{(E,A'), (E,E')\}$:  $4$ choices

$\{(C,D')\} \times \{(D, B')\}$: $1$ choice

$\{(C,B'), (C,D')\} \times \{(E,A'), (E,E')\}$: $4$ choices

$\{(D,B')\} \times \{(E,A'), (E,E')\}$: $2$ choices

For each of the $27$ excluded pairs above, there are $3!$ ways to arrange the remaining matches.  Hence, there are $27 \cdot 3!$ cases.

Three excluded pairs:  Again, we keep in mind that the excluded pairs must contain different men and different women.

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(B,A'), (B,C'), (B,D')\} \times \{(C,B')\}$: $3$ choices

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(B,A'), (B,C'), (B,D')\} \times \{(C,D')\}$: $2$ choices

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(B,A'), (B,C'), (B,D')\} \times \{(D,B')\}$: $3$ choices

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(B,C'), (B,D')\} \times \{(E,A')\}$: $2$ choices

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(C,B')\} \times \{(D,B')\}$: $1$ choice

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(C,B'), (C,D')\} \times \{(E,A')\}$: $2$ choices

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(D,B')\} \times \{(E,A')\}$: $1$ choice

$\{(B,A'), (B,C')\} \times \{(C,D')\} \times \{(D,B')\}$: $2$ choices

$\{(B,C'), (B,D')\} \times \{(C,B')\} \times \{(E,A')\}$: $2$ choices

$\{(B,C')\} \times \{(C,D')\} \times \{(E,A')\}$: $1$ choice

$\{(B,A'), (B,C'), (B,D')\} \times \{(C,B')\} \times \{(E,E')\}$: $3$ choices

$\{(B,A'), (B,C')\} \times \{(C,D')\} \times \{(E,E')\}$: $2$ choices

$\{(B,C'), (B,D')\} \times \{(D,B')\} \times \{(E,A')\}$: $2$ choices

$\{(B,A'), (B,C'), (B,D')\} \times \{(D,B')\} \times \{(E,E')\}$: $3$ choices

$\{(C,D')\} \times \{(D,B')\} \times \{(E,A'), (E,E')\}$: $2$ choices

For each of the $31$ cases above, the remaining pairs can be matched in $2!$ ways.  Hence, there are $31 \cdot 2!$ cases.

Four excluded pairs:  We keep in mind the same restrictions as above.

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(B,A'), (B,C')\} \times \{(C,D')\} \times \{(D,B')\}$: $2$ choices

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(B,C'), (B,D')\} \times \{(C,B')\} \times \{(E,A')\}$: $2$ choices

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(B,C')\} \times \{(C,D')\} \times \{(E,A')\}$: $1$ choice

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(B,C'), (B,D')\} \times \{(D,B')\} \times \{(E,A')\}$: $2$ choices

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(C,D')\} \times \{(D,B')\} \times \{(E,A')\}$: $1$ choice

$\{(B,C')\} \times \{(C,D')\} \times \{(D,B')\} \times \{(E,A')\}$: $1$ choice

$\{(B,A'), (B,C')\} \times \{(C,D')\} \times \{(D,B')\} \times \{(E,E')\}$: $2$ choices

For each of the $11$ cases above, there is only way to match the remaining pair.

Five excluded pairs:  Given the restriction stated above, there is only one choice.

$\{(A,E')\} \times \{(B,C')\} \times \{(C,D')\} \times \{(D,B')\} \times \{(E,A')\}$

By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of permissible matchings is 
$$5! - 9 \cdot 4! + 27 \cdot 3! - 31 \cdot 2! + 11 \cdot 1! - 1 \cdot 0! = 14$$
Since there are $5!$ ways of arranging the schedule for each set of matchings, there are $14 \cdot 5! = 2800$ permissible schedules.